# Accessing subdirectory in internal storage of Android app for write purposes

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, android-internal-storage

I have create an images subdirectory in the internal storage of my app. Hence the full path is,

`/data/data/{app_namespace}/images`

Now, I have successfully created a uri `/data/data/{app_namespace}/images/enh.jpeg` for storing images.

However, when I want to open the file for writing I face two issues in the two approaches I used respectively:

1. `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( uri_path)` : ENOENT No such file or directoy.
2. `FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(uri_path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` : File contains a path separator.

I want to understand how can I open `/data/data/{app_namespace}/images/enh.jpeg` for writing? Is there any other way which I don't know of?

Comment: I recommend that you use standard locations, like `getFilesDir()`, and subdirectories that you create under those.

Comment: @CommonsWare did you not read the question? As I said, the "images" directory is under the internal storage of my app, which I retrieved using context.getFilesDir().

Comment: No, it is not. `/data/data/{app_namespace}/images` is not under `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: It is. I can verify that /data/data/{app_namespace} is the path returned by getFilesDir()

Comment: Perhaps it is, on your device, for your account. The standard result for `getFilesDir()` will end in `files/`, as there are other peer directories of that (e.g., `shared_prefs/` for `SharedPreferences`, `databases/` for the default `SQLiteDatabase` location). The preceding path segments will include your `applicationId` and will have varying roots, though `/data/data/` is common. On most Android devices, `getFilesDir()` would return a value like `/data/data/.../files/`. And I have no idea what your device manufacturer was thinking with that `getFilesDir()` value.

Comment: Apologies. You are right. `getFilesDir()` returns `/data/data/{app_namespace}/files` precisely. Actually, my `images` folder is also inside `/data/data/{app_namespace}/files` . Sorry for the confusion. I forgot that there is a `files` directory at the end of the app namespace directory which I have not mentioned, which might have confused you. Apologies again.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. Actually, I was constructing the `uri_path` variable as follows

`uri_path = uri.getPath()`

This only returns `/images/enh.jpeg`, because the preceding part is encoded in the `authority` field of the `uri`. There are multiple solutions available elsewhere on the internet on how to extract the absolute path from a `Uri`, which I will omit here for brevity.